# Chrome Storage - Username/Password

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I'm having some problems with my chrome extension... I'm trying to save a username and password for auto-filling on another page - problem is it wont let me edit the username, although it fully works on password...

For clarification, brugernavn = username - adgangskode = password.

[Popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zgwe.png)

The javascript activated through html popup is following:

Username:

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function load(event) {
      chrome.storage.local.get(['brugernavn'], function(result) {
          if (result !== undefined && result.brugernavn !== undefined) {
              document.getElementById('brugernavn').value = result.brugernavn;
    }
});

  document.getElementById('gem').onclick = function() {
    chrome.storage.local.remove('brugernavn');
      chrome.storage.local.set({'brugernavn': document.getElementById('brugernavn').value});
    };
});
```

Password:

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function load(event) {
      chrome.storage.local.get(['adgangskode'], function(result) {
          if (result !== undefined && result.adgangskode !== undefined) {
              document.getElementById('adgangskode').value = result.adgangskode;
          }
      });

  document.getElementById('gem').onclick = function() {
    chrome.storage.local.remove('adgangskode');
      chrome.storage.local.set({'adgangskode': document.getElementById('adgangskode').value});
};
  });
```

So password works fully, but I'm not able to edit username to save a new username.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of confusion and tears it's working. Not quite sure why or how, but it does.

I separated the script, and then it kind of worked... But fully worked when I put the password into an array.

Code below: (Will try to make it less awkward at some point)

```
    var storage = chrome.storage.local;

brugernavn ();
function brugernavn () {
  window.addEventListener('load', function load(event) {
      storage.get(['brugernavn'], function(result) {
          if (result !== undefined && result.brugernavn !== undefined) {
              document.getElementById('brugernavn').value = result.brugernavn;
        }
    });

      document.getElementById('gem').onclick = function() {
        storage.remove('brugernavn');
          storage.set({'brugernavn': document.getElementById('brugernavn').value});

          storage.remove('adgangskode');
            var adgangs = document.getElementById('adgangskode').value;
            storage.set({'adgangskode' : adgangs});
        };
    });
}
```

*Search notes:
chrome extension password username login chrome.storage chrome.storage.local*

Answer (score 0):

## Optimized script:

```
/*----STORAGE SAVE----*/
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {

  var getValueBruger = document.getElementById('brugernavn').value;
  var getValueAdgangs = document.getElementById('adgangskode').value;

  storage.set({
    "brugernavn": getValueBruger,
    "adgangskode": getValueAdgangs
  });
});
```